# SQL Server UDF refresh

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have altered the column datatype in one of my tables from int to decimal.

I have a UDF referencing the columns of this table.

How can I ensure my UDF returns decimals rather than int without having to re-create it?

(For view, I know we can use sp_refreshview, not sure about UDF).

Thanks,
Rashmi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you are talking about an inline TVF in which case you can use

```
EXEC sp_refreshsqlmodule 'YourTVF'
```