# How to refresh user-defined functions

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server UDF refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683732/sql-server-udf-refresh)

The system stored procedure `sp_refreshview` can be used to validate and recompile views in SQL Server.

How can I do the same for scalar functions and table functions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should look at [sp_refreshsqlmodule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326754.aspx).

Comment: Just what I needed. Thanks Aaron!